# How to keep user logged in app after closing it?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, authentication, userdefaults

I am trying to keep the user logged in. I tried with the code below. The app uses Firebase for storing data and logging in users.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class WelcomeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var logInButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var signUpButton: UIButton!
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        logInButton.backgroundColor = .clear
        logInButton.layer.cornerRadius = 27
        logInButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        logInButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemGreen.cgColor
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let secondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "EcoMapViewController")

            show(secondVC, sender: self)
        } else {
            do {
                try Auth.auth().signOut()
                navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
            } catch let signOutError as NSError {
                print("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it working and what is not?

Comment: authentification works perfectly, but the app requires users to log in over and over again after closing it completely. Heard something about user defaults but it doesn't work

Comment: Firebase auth maintains the user between app sessions; from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users#the_current_user) *The instance persists the user's state, so that refreshing the page (in a browser) or restarting the application doesn't lose the user's information*. It doesn't appear the code you're using is the suggested code for authentication checking. See [Get the currently signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user)

Answer (score 0):

`Userdefault` in this case is *not* a viable solution as they are not encrypted and can be accessed and modified by anyone. A good solution is to use Apple's [keychain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services). I would recommend using this open source keyChain Api [module](https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper), so that it becomes easier to interface with it.

Comment: Great point about Userdefaults but the rest is unnecessary and Firebase Auth keeps users authenticated. See my comment to the question.

Comment: Oh nice, I didn't know that. Thank for pointing it out !!